# FFMPEG audio upsampling/resampling to 48000 Hz causes sound wheeze/noises/dissortions

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, resampling

I'm using the following example http://svn.gnumonks.org/tags/21c3-video/upstream/ffmpeg-0.4.9-pre1/output_example.c to make videos. If I use 44100 Hz for the output audio format it seems that all is fine, but if I use 48000 Hz any audio gets wheeze.

Any suggestion, please.

Here are input audio and encoded video with that audio but in 48 kHz that has wheezing audio:
http://www.unsode.com/test.zip

Comment: If you are using a recent version of FFmpeg, consider filing a bug report. Note that the code you linked to is from 2003—this is a long time in FFmpeg-land, and almost guaranteed to fail.

Comment: Dear slhck, could you, please, provide me with an example that uses new methods, api, etc. Thank you

Comment: I can't, sorry. I've never used the API programmatically.